# Explanation of the d3 url() function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510452/setting-color-of-marker-end-arrow-in-d3-js) and my first end arrow looks like this when I inspect it in the browser:

`<path class="link myclass" style="marker-end: url(&quot;#end-arrow0&quot;);" d="M1000.9069448181974,1083.8570639658033A99.05453406424766,99.05453406424766 0 0,1 1069.759481983105,1012.6452050893477"/>`

What is the url() function doing?

Comment: It's not a `d3` function but rather part of the `SVG` [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html)

Comment: @Mark Thank you!  That pointed me in the right direction.